# Parsing swift arrays into valid json

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift

So the issue I am facing is that i have two arrays in an ios app which i need to store in a remote mySQL database, which i would like to accomplish using php and json. I haven't, however, despite several days of work, managed to get the arrays in the ios app converted into json code which doesn't crash the app. The arrays are populated by a qr code reader and input field, and there is always an equal amount of items in each array. Currently the code below generates the following json:

`json string = {"b":"[\n\n]","p":"[\n\n]"}`

No matter what changes i do, the app seems to crash with the following error:
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** +[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:options:error:]: Invalid top-level type in JSON write', or alternatively it says Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.} with some of my other experiments (like the version currently below)

```
var productArray = [String]()
var amountArray = [String]()



func addTapped(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    print("Running add func")
    do {
        var test1 = ""
        var test2 = ""
        //Convert to Data
        let jsonData1 = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: amountArray, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted)
        let jsonData2 = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: productArray, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted)

        //Convert back to string. Usually only do this for debugging
        if let JSONString1 = String(data: jsonData1, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) {
            print(JSONString1)
            test1 = JSONString1
        }
        if let JSONString2 = String(data: jsonData2, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) {
            print(JSONString2)
            test2 = JSONString2
        }
        //In production, you usually want to try and cast as the root data structure. Here we are casting as a dictionary. If the root object is an array cast as [AnyObject].
        var json1 = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData1, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as? [String: AnyObject]
        var json2 = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData2, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as? [String: AnyObject]






        let dict = ["json1": test1, "json2": test2] as [String: Any]


        print("All JSON should print below")
        print(dict)
        if let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dict, options: .prettyPrinted) {
            let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.server.com/receiver")!
            let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url as URL)
            request.httpMethod = "POST"
            request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
            request.httpBody = jsonData

            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest){ data,response,error in
                if error != nil{
                    print(error?.localizedDescription)
                    return
                }

                do {
                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary

                    if let parseJSON = json {
                        let resultValue:String = parseJSON["success"] as! String;
                        print("result: \(resultValue)")
                        print(parseJSON)
                    }
                } catch let error as NSError {
                    print(error)
                }        
            }          
            task.resume()
        }


    } catch {
        print("Oops")
    }

}
```

Comment: in which line your code stopped ?

Comment: @KKRocks That's part of my issue - XCode thinks that information is unnecessary despite having zombie objects enabled, so it doesn't tell me that.

Comment: set exception breakpoint  and run code again : http://stackoverflow.com/a/17802868/3901620

Comment: Noticed that one of the things i had tried to do broke the code slightly, i fixed it above (just a minor variable name issue). Now The program doesn't crash, instead it says Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}

Comment: if let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dict, options: .allowFragments) try this line

Comment: It says / Type 'JSONSerialization.WritingOptions' has no member 'allowFragments' when i try that.

Comment: Just replace it                         let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary  to allowFragments. 
you can see now the error message is diffrent

Comment: I'm sorry, but i'm not sure what you want me to replace with that.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution is using [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON)

Whit that, if you have a String you can use `var json = JSON.parse(yourString)`